# How to mock IDataReader.NextResult?

Tags: c#, moq, sqldatareader

I have a stored procedure which returns two resultsets.  I process it like this in my production code:

```
Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (Rdr.Read())
{
    // process first resultset
}
Rdr.NextResult();
while (Rdr.Read())
{
    // process second resultset
}
```

I'm not sure how this should be mocked (using Moq).

When testing single resultset stored procedures, my test code looks like this:

```
DataTableReader testDataReader = testData.CreateDataReader();  //testData is a DataTable
commandMock.Setup(m => m.ExecuteReader()).Returns(testDataReader)
```

How do I setup my mocks to mock the second resultset?

Comment: You could use [`SetupSequence()`](https://github.com/moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them into a `DataSet` and create a reader over that

```cs
var dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.Tables.Add(testData1);
dataset.Tables.Add(testData2);
var testDataReader = dataset.CreateDataReader();
commandMock.Setup(m => m.ExecuteReader()).Returns(testDataReader)
```